# read data into R table format

Tags: r

I want to read this data into R. When I read in use the read.csv command, it just creates 2 columns, instead of reading in the data row by row and putting the data into a table.

Here is a snapshot of the data rows.[image]

Here is my R code:

```
data = read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
```

Current output:

[image]

But I would like to create a structured table that places the data from each row into the associated row, based on the position it is in the row.

Thank you!

Comment: It is best if you provide a snippet of your data in raw format. Also, My suggestion would be to forget about `file.choose` and use a proper path. You will thank yourself in a month's time.

Comment: Try `data = read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)`

Comment: @Duck that did not work. It still reads the data in without being in each column

Comment: How many rows are there in your file? Can you paste into your post the output of `dput(readLines("df.csv", 10))` where `df.csv` is your CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [video game sales data](https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales/downloads/videogamesales.zip/2) from Kaggle.com. To read it with `read.csv()`, use the following code. Note that I've included the first 10 rows of raw data in my answer so it is reproducible.

```
vgsalesData <- "Rank,Name,Platform,Year,Genre,Publisher,NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales
1,Wii Sports,Wii,2006,Sports,Nintendo,41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74
2,Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985,Platform,Nintendo,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24
3,Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008,Racing,Nintendo,15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.82
4,Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33
5,Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996,Role-Playing,Nintendo,11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.37
6,Tetris,GB,1989,Puzzle,Nintendo,23.2,2.26,4.22,0.58,30.26
7,New Super Mario Bros.,DS,2006,Platform,Nintendo,11.38,9.23,6.5,2.9,30.01
8,Wii Play,Wii,2006,Misc,Nintendo,14.03,9.2,2.93,2.85,29.02
9,New Super Mario Bros. Wii,Wii,2009,Platform,Nintendo,14.59,7.06,4.7,2.26,28.62
10,Duck Hunt,NES,1984,Shooter,Nintendo,26.93,0.63,0.28,0.47,28.31
"

sales <- read.csv(text=vgsalesData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(sales)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(sales)
  Rank                     Name Platform Year        Genre Publisher NA_Sales EU_Sales JP_Sales
1    1               Wii Sports      Wii 2006       Sports  Nintendo    41.49    29.02     3.77
2    2        Super Mario Bros.      NES 1985     Platform  Nintendo    29.08     3.58     6.81
3    3           Mario Kart Wii      Wii 2008       Racing  Nintendo    15.85    12.88     3.79
4    4        Wii Sports Resort      Wii 2009       Sports  Nintendo    15.75    11.01     3.28
5    5 Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue       GB 1996 Role-Playing  Nintendo    11.27     8.89    10.22
6    6                   Tetris       GB 1989       Puzzle  Nintendo    23.20     2.26     4.22
  Other_Sales Global_Sales
1        8.46        82.74
2        0.77        40.24
3        3.31        35.82
4        2.96        33.00
5        1.00        31.37
6        0.58        30.26
>
```